# Potential memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, string, memory-leaks

The following code resolves the problem of removing the duplicate characters in a string.

```
void removeDuplicatesEff(char *str) 
{
    if (!str)
        return;

    int len = strlen(str);
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    const int sz = (1<<CHAR_BIT); 
    bool hit[sz] = {false};

    int tail = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) 
    {
        if (!hit[str[i]]) 
        {
            str[tail] = str[i];
            ++tail;
            hit[str[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    str[tail] = 0;
}
```

After setting `str[tail]=0` in the last step, if `char *str` does contain duplicate characters, its size will be smaller, i.e. `tail`. But I am wondering whether there is a memory leak here? It seems to me that, later, we cannot releasing all the spaces that is allocated to original `char *str`. Is this right? If so, how can we resolve it in such situations?

Comment: I have a question, possibly a stupid one, but I don't understand what exactly are you doing with the array of size 256? What does it represent?

Comment: @Kraken As a hash table, to record the frequency of each element in `char *`.

Comment: @herohuyongto Yeah, but why 256? Should not it be 128?

Comment: @herohuyongto I might be messing up something big, but each character can have ASCII as 0-127 only right?

Comment: @Kraken To handle `€` by taking [Extended ASCII Codes](http://www.ascii-code.com/) into consideration.

Comment: It should probably be (1 << CHAR_BIT).

Comment: @Casey It's equal to 256. Will `CHAR_BIT` be different for different  computer architectures?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yes, the C standard mandates that `CHAR_BIT` is defined  in `<limits.h>` to be the number of bits in the representation of `char`. It must be at least 8, but theoretically has no maximum size (N1570 (pre-C11 draft) §5.2.4.2.1/1). And symbolic constants *always* beat magic numbers for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems to me that, later, we cannot releasing all the spaces that is allocated to original char *str. Is this right?

No. The length of a zero-terminated string is completely decoupled from the size of the allocated memory buffer, and the system treats it separately. As long as every allocation is followed by a symmetrical deallocation (e.g. there’s a `free` for every `malloc` operation), you’re safe.

> But I am wondering whether there is a memory leak here?

Arguably, yes, this is *still* a leak since it (temporarily) uses more memory than required. However, that is usually not a problem since the memory gets released eventually. Except in very special circumstances, this would therefore not be considered a leak.

That said, the code is quite unconventional and definitely longer than necessary (it also assumes that `CHAR_BIT == 8` but that’s another matter). For instance, you can initialise your flag array much easier, saving a loop:

```
bool hit[256] = {false};
```

And why is your loop going over the string one-based, and why is the first character handled separately?

Comment: So `free(str)` will free all the spaces that originally allocated?

Comment: Your second part of the answer is a bit misleading. In commonly used terminology a memory leak is an dynamically allocated object to which you don't have a reference anymore. This is not the case, here.

Comment: @Jens That’s why I’m using “arguably”. But yeah, I’ll clarify this more.

Comment: @herohuyongtao The test case is meaningless because it doesn’t do what you think it does. Remove the `a[4] = 0;` line, the “length” will *always* be 4. It’s the size of a pointer, not the length of the array.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just realized. Stupid of me. Deleted.

Comment: For your question, string one-based is equivalent to zero-based (at least here). Right?

Comment: @herohuyongtao My question relates to the fact that your code is more complex than necessary. You have duplicate code because you treat `str[0]` separately, which isn’t necessary.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see. Will do as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: What is the best hash table size in this case, `1<<CHAR_BIT`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yes, exactly. Additionally, you cannot directly use `char` values as an index, since `char` can have *negative* values! You need to convert the value to an `unsigned int` beforehand first. That’s unfortunate but necessary.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And better to pass in `unsigned char *` to handle [Extended ASCII Codes](http://www.ascii-code.com/) like `€`.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no leak. You only modify the contents of the array by putting in `0` and not its length.

Also you shouldn't initialize your `hit` array by assignment with the `for`-loop. A standard initialization

```
bool hit[256] = { 0 };
```

would suffice and can be replaced by your compiler by the most efficient form of initialization.

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory leak in your case. Memory leak happens when you allocate memory from head and not freeing after using it. In your case you are not allocating any memory from heap. You are using local variables which are stored in stack and freed when control returns from that function.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is just changing the placement of the terminator character. It doesn't actually change the size of the allocated memory. It's actually a very common operation, and there is no risk of memory leak from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not have a memory leak. Performing a `delete []` or `free()` on `str` will deallocate all allocated memory just fine because that information is stored elsewhere and does not depend on the type of data being stored in `str`.

Answer (score 1):

> But I am wondering whether there is a memory leak here? It seems to me that, later, we cannot releasing all the spaces that is allocated to original char *str

There's probably no problem here.  the storage for `str` has been allocated in one of the following ways:

- reserved space on the stack
- malloc space on the heap
- reserved space in the data segment.

In the first case,  all of the space disappears when the stack frame unwinds.  In the second case, malloc records the number of bytes allocated (usually in the memory location just before the first byte pointed to by the malloc return value.  In the third case, the space is allocated only once when the program is first loaded.

No possibility of a leak there.